# Azure DevOps CI Pipeline for a pySpark project

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-devops

I am trying to implement azure devops on few of my pyspark projects.

some of the projects are developed in pyCharm and some are in intelliJ with python API.

Below is the code structure commited in the git repository.
[image]

setup.py is the build file used to create .egg file.

I have tried few of the steps as shown below to create a build pipeline in the devops.
[image]
But the python installation part/execution part is failing with below error.

```
##[error]The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.7.9\x64\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

I would prefer UI API for building and creating .egg files, If not possible YAML files.

Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following steps and it succeeds!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used `Use Python` step and then all works like a charm

[image]

Can you show details of `Install Python` step?

Comment: yeah...I tried with use python and it was successful. Thank you very much for your response!